# How to convert wide string to ASCII

Tags: c++, character-encoding, ascii

I'm looking for a way of converting a `wstring` into a plain `string` containing only ASCII characters. Any character that isn't present in ASCII (0-127) should be converted to the closest ASCII character. If there is no similar ASCII character, the character should be omitted.

To illustrate, let's assume the following wide string:

```
wstring text(L"A naïve man called 晨 was having piña colada and crème brûlée.");
```

The converted version I'm looking for is this (notice the absence of diacritics):

```
string("A naive man called  was having pina colada and creme brulee.")
```

**Edit:**

Regarding the **purpose**: I'm writing an application that analyzes English texts. The input files are UTF-8 and may contain special characters. A part of my application uses a library written in C that only understands ASCII. So I need a way of "dumbing down" the text to ASCII without losing too much information.

Regarding the **precise requirements**: Any character that is a diacritic version of an ASCII character should be converted to that ASCII character; all other characters should be omitted. So `ı`, `ĩ`, and `î` should become `i` because they are all versions of the small Latin letter i. The character `ɩ` (iota), on the other hand, while visually similar, is not a version of the small Latin letter i and should thus be omitted.

Comment: *"Any character that isn't present in ASCII (0-127) should be converted to the closest ASCII character. If there is no similar ASCII character, the character should be omitted."* This does not sound well defined at all. Is † almost t?

Comment: You just have to define "similar" and "closest". A huge table, perhaps?

Comment: *to allow for a wider range of possible solutions* that goes against the site.  We want a well defined question that has a narrow scope for answers.  As is IMHO this is too broad.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin  and build a table of conversions.  only the latin characters need to be converted, any uni-code above that won't map

Comment: @NathanOliver: Good point. I've removed my comment and edited the answer.

Comment: Maybe useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string

Comment: Maybe useful, see C/C++ library behind this  [demo:](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/translit), select `Accents` as sample, `Latin` as Source1 and `ASCII` as target...

Comment: @mindriot how is a Python answer using libraries that aren't available in C++ useful?

Comment: @MarkRansom Because it led me to what I have now posted below as an answer. Python solution → Google "unidecode" → find (basic) C++ port. But there's a reason why I wrote it as a comment rather than an answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On GitHub, there is [unidecode-cxx](https://github.com/mapbox/node-unidecode-cxx) which is a (somewhat unfinished) C++ port of [node-unidecode](https://github.com/FGRibreau/node-unidecode), which is in turn a JavaScript port of Perl's [Text::Unicode](http://search.cpan.org/%7Esburke/Text-Unidecode-0.04/lib/Text/Unidecode.pm).  The C++ version is a bit rough around the edges, but the example in `src/unidecode.cxx` can be modified to convert your example string,

> `A naïve man called 晨 was having piña colada and crème brûlée.`

as follows:

> `A naive man called Chen  was having pina colada and creme brulee.`

In order to get the code to compile without Gyp (something I've never used and haven't had the time to figure out just now), I had to modify the code somewhat (quick  and dirty):

- Add `#include <iostream>` to `src/unidecode.cxx`, and add the following `main` routine:

  ```
  int main() {
    string output_buf;
    string input_buf = "A naïve man called 晨 was having piña colada and crème brûlée.";
    unidecode(&input_buf, &output_buf);
    cout << output_buf.c_str() << endl;
  }
  ```
- Replace all mentions of `NULL` in `src/data.cxx` with `nullptr`

Then I compiled with

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o unidecode unidecode.cxx
```

to get the desired result.

The code looks like a fairly primitive port and could do with some improvements, especially into more "proper" C++.  It internally uses a statically compiled conversion table, which can probably be adapted to suit your needs if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

`wstring` is a `string` of `wchar` which is a character that may have size of 2 or 4 bytes. 
Meanwhile UTF8 is a variable length encoding with symbol size of 1-4 bytes. So your request is not fully consistent.

Assuming you've figured out how exactly data is stored in your strings I'd suggest you to check out [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/) library to do further conversions.

You can normalize your strings and then remove all diacritics. But still you'll be left with Greek, Cyrillic and stuff. 
Or you can use [transliteration](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-ICU-Transliterators) feature which is more like what you're looking for.

The mindriot's solution is more concise but still you need to convert you `wstring` to proper UTF8 sequence.